# ¿Cómo almacenar subdocumentos en MongoDB, usando esquemas de Mongoose?

Tags: nodejs, api, mongodb, postman, json-schema

Buenas noches comunidad De StackOverFlow,

Amigos deseo de su apoyo para saber como o cual es la mejor manera de poder insertar los siguientes documentos a mi de datos a mi BD en Mongo, tengo la siguiente informacion:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo estos dos documentos en mi BD de mongo,  la primera la realice por consola y la segunda realizado por postman, los datos quisiera que se guarden como en el primer documento, donde estan anidados uno con otros. Pero no se logran guardar de esa forma, como se muestra si le paso los datos por postman

la estructura de datos es la siguiente:

```
  "groups" : {
        "idGroups" : 1,
        "idUsers":1,
        "createdAt" : ISODate("2020-10-14T05:00:00.000Z"),
        "nameGroups" : "admin"
        },
    "users" : {
            "idUser" : 1,
            "name" : "Jonas",
            "lastame" : "Leon",
            "idCard" : 123456,
            "ProfilePhotoUrl":""  
        },
    "employee" : {
            "idEmployeeOrigin":1,
            "idUser" : 1,
            "name" : "Jonas"
        },
    "departament" : {
                "idDepartament":2, 
                "nameDepartament":"Gerency"
        },
    "message" : {
            "idMessage":1,
            "messageContent" : "Hola Andres",
            "idStatusMessage" : 2,
            "dateMessage" : ISODate("2020-10-14T05:00:00.000Z")
        },
    "idStatusMessage":{
        "idStatusMessage":2,
        "nameStatusMessage":"read"
    },
    "date" : ISODate("2020-10-14T05:00:00.000Z"),
    "urlFile":""
```

mi Backend es el siguiente:

controllers/bots.js

```
saveBot: function(req, res){
    var bot = new Bot();

    var params = req.body;
    bot.groups = params.groups;
    bot.users = params.users;
    bot.employee = params.idemployee;
    bot.departament = params.departament;
    bot.message = params.message;
    bot.idStatusMessage = params.idStatusMessage;
    bot.date=params.date;
    

bot.save((err, botStored) => {
        if(err) return res.status(500).send({message: 'Error al guardar el documento.'});

        if(!botStored) return res.status(404).send({message: 'No se ha podido guardar el proyecto.'});

        return res.status(200).send({bot: botStored});
    });
},
```

y este es mi modelo en el backend

models/bots.js

```
'use strict'

var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var BotSchema = Schema({

    groups : Object,
    users : Object,
    employee :Object,
    departament:Object, 
    message:Object,
    idStatusMessage:Object,
    date: Date,
    
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Bot', BotSchema);
// projects  --> guarda los documents en la coleccion
```

tengo entendido que puedo realizar este tipo de acciones creando una interfaz para gestionar un objeto donde pueda definir las variables, pero desconozco un poco de como poder crear una

Comment: No existe una *mejor forma*. Aunque existen técnicas que te ayudan a organizar los datos de tu aplicación. Tu pregunta es totalmente basada en opiniones. ¿Cuál es el problema o error específico que tienes actualmente? Por otro lado, si usas Mongoose para el modelado de datos ¿porqué usar el tipo genérico `Object` cuando puedes usar el tipo `Schema`?

Comment: Hola Mauricio, muchas gracias por tu apoyo, solo requiero que al poder guardar los datos que envio por postman se guarde de forma anidado como se observa en el primer documento en la BD, no como el segundo documento.

Comment: Entonces cambia el título de tu pregunta por algo como ***¿Cómo almacenar subdocumentos en MongoDB, usando esquemas de Mongoose?***. Por otro lado, tal vez el problema está en la forma en que estás enviando los datos desde Postman, o incluso, la forma en que tu *backend* los procesa. Saludos

Comment: realice un cambio en el backend en la forma de enviar los datos, anidando los schemas por grupos y realizando un schema superior agrupando todos los datos principales.